# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index on JMETER

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

I have an application for which I have recorded Jmeter scripts to conduct load testing. Authorization happens via Azure AD.

I have co-related the auth-related such as access tokens, refresh tokens and id tokens that are generated dynamically and also parameterized them in a request that is responsible for calling the API and which would probably require those tokens to authorize the call to the API.

However, I get an error:-

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 98:
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2938)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3109)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3197)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3139)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:1063)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:615)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1270)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have co-related 3 dynamic tokens which are generated as part of the auth token request.

Screenshots in the below link:-

[Regular Expression Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga35r.png)

[Setting parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLs6y.png)

[Error on Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQhtm.png)

Comment: I think you need to put Authorization in a HTTP header instead of a parameter.

Comment: I haven't counted, but index 98 does seem to be around the `:` between `pages` and `listTiles`, and `:` is a reserved character. You need to percent-encode the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these "tokens" should go into the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as placing them as request parameters adds them to the request URL.

If your application expects the tokens to be a part of the URL (which is kind of strange) then you either need to tick the `URL Encode?` boxes or wrap the values which can contain the [characters requiring encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. What I did wrong, was that I did not put the "$" sign before the parameters in the URL.

**How I resolved the issue:**
When I got the exception, I counted the characters in the URL till the index (given in the exception) which made me realize that something is wrong with the given index, then I checked the tutorial which I was following, and Hoorah! the issue has been found.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7dXw.png)

Answer (score 0):

In jmeter there is a checkbox for _urlencode() function.Refer the image

[image]